# Get Value of HTML cells in row clicked with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I am populating a html table based on data stored in parse.com.  So the table is dynamically populated, I am including editing options for the user to add, delete and edit a row.  I have managed to incorporate delete and add to the table however, my problem is I need to get the data in the cells of the row on which I click the edit button...
So what I want to do is when the user clicks on the edit button I'll open a dialog with the table row in it populated with the data in the row they have clicked, in this dialog they can change data and save.  I've attached a screenshot of a sample table.  So if the user clicks on the edit button on the second row, I need to obtain the data in each cell to populate the dialog.  [image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //table row
    var tdUuid = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdProx = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdOffer = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");

    alert(tdUuid.html()); //for testing
```

This comes up as undefined.

I've also tried:

```
var value = $(this).children().get(1).text();
```

I've tried to display this in an alert but the alert doesn't display so I'm assuming this is way wrong...

If anyone could help me I'd greatly appreciate it.  I'm VERY new to html/javascript and I'm feeling my way around in the dark!

**EDIT**
Here is my html as requested:

```
<div id="EditDialog" title="Edit iBeacon">
            <p class ="editInfo">
                Please edit fields and click save
            </p>
            <table id ="editingTable" class ="beaconTable ">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>UUID</th>
                    <th>Proximity</th>
                    <th>Offer</th>
                </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <button id ="saveButton" class ="btnSave">Save</button> <button id ="cancelButton" class ="btnCan">Cancel</button> 

        </div>

        <div id= "tableContainerHolder">
            <div id = "tableContainer">
                <button id ="buttonAdd">Add iBeacon</button>
                <table id ="iBeaconTable" class ="beaconTable " >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>UUID</th>
                            <th>Proximity</th>
                            <th>Offer</th>   
                            <th>Editing Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#EditDialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**FURTHER EDIT**

Here is how I populate my table:

```
 $('#iBeaconTable').append('<tr><td id = "uuid">' + object.get('uuid') + '</td><td = "proxId">' + object.get('proximity') + '</td><td = "offerId">' + object.get('offer_content') + '</td><td><Button id = "btnEdit" onclick = "openDialog()">Edit</Button><Button id = "btnDelete" onclick = "Delete()">Delete</Button></td></tr>');
```

So I add the buttons each time in each row.

**additional edit**

Apologies for omitting code

```
function openDialog() {

    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //table row
    var tdUuid = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdProx = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdOffer = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");

     $("#EditDialog").dialog("open");

    $('#editingTable').append('<tr><td id = "uuid">' +tdUuid.innerHTML+ '</td><td = "proxId">' + tdProx.html()+ '</td><td = "offerId">' +  tdOffer.html());

}
```

The code in the `openDialog()` is what I had originally posted.

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: So `this` is the EDIT button??? Provide more context of your code!

Comment: Not sure if this will *solve* the issue, but `var par = $(this).closest('tr');` is a little cleaner (and futureproof - you could nest your buttons in another div, etc.)...

Comment: hard to say without html, anyway if you are using jQuery last line should be alert($(tdUuid).html());

Comment: How do you populate TABLE? Where is the EDIT buttons click handler???

Comment: You have no `td` cell in your markup?

Comment: @RahilWazir But indeed OP didn't provide the relevant code regarding the EDIT buttons of each row

Comment: You HTML is then invalid, IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: why negative mark?  apologies if I didn't provide full info originally..

Comment: @DJ-DOO You still didn't have provide all relevant code. We have to devine what is `openDialog()` method...

Comment: I have provided all my code, the html, the js attempt and how I populate the cells...what else is required?  As I stressed in the original post, I am VERY new to html and js so I had hoped people would be a little forgiving

Comment: @DJ-DOO It would be way better if you create working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: ok..I'll give that a shot

Comment: I'm struggling with fiddle..it doesn't recognise js in html code

Comment: Can people explain why I am getting negative votes?

Comment: @Rahil Wazir I have tried working with fiddle but the fact that my table is being populate from parse and contains sensitive data means that I can't recreate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

values in table are selected only after adding data dynamically. To get td values

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr')
var tdUuid = $(tr).find('td').eq(0).text();
var tdProx = $(tr).find('td').eq(1).text();
var tdOffer = $(tr).find('td').eq(2).text();
```

Hope this should work.

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately that doesn't work...it wasn't myself that marked you down, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check it now.. I updated the answer. I assumed there is no element in td, like <td>some value</td> .

Comment: A year later. Just wanted to say that this answer actually works for me.