# Get specific cell value from specific row in dynamically populated table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My web application gets values from a JSON object, and populates a table with its values along with an edit and delete button on each row. I want my script to be able to know which rows edit button was pressed, along with that rows cell values.

*While formatting my question, I stumbled (I searched for an hour before deciding to ask) upon this exact same question, but it did not contain any solution that worked for me:* [Get Value of HTML cells in row clicked with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826350/get-value-of-html-cells-in-row-clicked-with-javascript)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">     
    <h4>Persons</h4>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="persons_table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    //dynamically generated rows goes here
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addBtn">New person</button>
</div>
```

Function for populating the table:

```
function handlePersons(data){ //data is a response from an API (JSON)
    var table = document.getElementById('persons_table');
    data.forEach(function(object) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = 
        '<td>' + object.ID + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.Name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.Email + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.PhoneNumber + '</td>' +
        '<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="editBtn" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button></p></td>' +
        '<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></p></td>';
        table.appendChild(tr);
        });
    }
```

Just in case you need it, this is my ajax call to fetch JSON data:

```
function getPersons(){
    var settings = {
            "async" : true,
            "crossDomain" : true,
            "url" : "...",
            "method" : "GET",
            "headers" : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "Authorization": "...",
                "cache-control" : "no-cache"
            },
            "processData" : false,
            "data" : ""
        }
        return $.ajax(settings);
}
```

Function call:

```
getPersons().done(handlePersons)
```

In practice it looks like this:
[image]

My question is, when I press the edit button on the first row, how can I let my script know it was the edit button on that specific row that was pressed, and how can I for example console.log that rows name (John)?
This is what I've tried:

```
$('#editBtn').on('click', () => {

    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //to choose table row, also tried one 
                                         //and three .parent() because I don't 
                                         //quite understand this

    var namevalue = par.children("td:nth-child(2)").val(); //also tried with .text()
    console.log(namevalue); //.val = undefined and .text = empty string

});
```

```
$('#editBtn').on('click', () => { //also tried with onclick="function" 
                                  //on the button instead of
                                  //jQuery just in case

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    var tdID = $(tr).find('td').eq(0).text();
    var tdName = $(tr).find('td').eq(1).text();
    var tdEmail = $(tr).find('td').eq(2).text();
    var tdPhone = $(tr).find('td').eq(3).text();

    console.log(tdName); //.text logs empty string, .val logs undefined again

});
```

JSON data after request from @Cybernetic. This is edited a little bit to not reveal any sensitive information, but should still produce the same result in my code.

```
[
    {
        "CustomValues": {},
        "Comment": "Here is John",
        "Deleted": false,
        "ID": 1,
        "InfoID": 4,
        "Role": null,
        "StatusCode": null,
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "UpdatedBy": null,
        "Info": {            
            "DefaultEmailID": 1,
            "DefaultPhoneID": 2,
            "Deleted": false,
            "ID": 3,
            "Name": "John",
            "PhoneNumber": "123-123-123",
            "Email": "john@mail.com"                      
        }
    },
    {
        "CustomValues": {},
        "Comment": "Here is Mike",
        "Deleted": false,
        "ID": 2,
        "InfoID": 6,
        "Role": null,
        "StatusCode": null,
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "UpdatedBy": null,
        "Info": {            
            "DefaultEmailID": 3,
            "DefaultPhoneID": 4,
            "Deleted": false,
            "ID": 6,
            "Name": "Mike",
            "PhoneNumber": "321-321-321",
            "Email": "mike@mail.com"                      
        }
    }   
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of example JSON data so we can recreate the table on our end and work out a solution?

Comment: @Cybernetic Sure, see edit at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery is used, there are two undocumented rules you should follow:

> 1. Do not use id unless required (such as Bootstrap `data-` attributes), use class. Note: The demo below demonstrates how we can use class exclusively and no longer have any dependency on ids.
> 2. Do not use on-event attributes `<button` <del>onclick="fnc()"</del> `>`

The first rule is applied to demo and the second rule isn't relevant just added for completeness. Also, ids must be unique -- the OP code provided was generating duplicate `button#editBtn`.

Dynamically added elements cannot be bound to events so any attempts to add 'click' events to the edit/delete buttons would fail. Only elements that existed at load time can be registered to events, so any ancestor element from `<tbody>` to `document` can be registered to the click event and then the event can be delegated to the edit/delete buttons. In general terms, delegating events involves programming pattern used to specifically determine which elements react to events and which elements ignore such events.

jQuery event methods make event delegation easy by providing the first (second for `.on()`) parameter called `eventData`. `eventData` is an optional parameter in the format of a selector string (same as what is commonly in `$(`...`)`). That will become the context of the function -- `$(this)` or `$(event.target)` -- essentially the clicked button.
**Ancestor**                   **eventData**
              ⇩                                  ⇩

> ```
> $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {...
> ```

**Details commented in demo**

```js
/* 
A: jQuery .append() is not destructive like .innerHTML
   Template literal is easier and cleaner than literal   
   strings.
*/
function handleContacts(data) {
  data.forEach(function(object) {
    $('.contacts').append(`<tr> 
      <td class='content'>${object.ID}</td>
       <td class='content'>${object.Info.Name}</td>
       <td class='content'>${object.Info.Email}</td>
       <td class='content'>${object.Info.PhoneNumber}</td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button></p></td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></td></tr>`); //A
  });
}

var data = [{
    "CustomValues": {},
    "Comment": "Here is John",
    "Deleted": false,
    "ID": 1,
    "InfoID": 4,
    "Role": null,
    "StatusCode": null,
    "UpdatedAt": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "Info": {
      "DefaultEmailID": 1,
      "DefaultPhoneID": 2,
      "Deleted": false,
      "ID": 3,
      "Name": "John",
      "PhoneNumber": "123-123-1231",
      "Email": "john@mail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "CustomValues": {},
    "Comment": "Here is Mike",
    "Deleted": false,
    "ID": 2,
    "InfoID": 6,
    "Role": null,
    "StatusCode": null,
    "UpdatedAt": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "Info": {
      "DefaultEmailID": 3,
      "DefaultPhoneID": 4,
      "Deleted": false,
      "ID": 6,
      "Name": "Mike",
      "PhoneNumber": "321-321-3213",
      "Email": "mike@mail.com"
    }
  }
];

// button.add is clicked -- handleContacts() is called
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
  handleContacts(data);
});

/*
Delegate click event to document
$(this) or $(e.target) is button.delete
Get the .closest() <tr> and remove() it.
*/
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
});

/*
Delegate click event to document
Note: Any dynamically added elements cannot be bound to 
      events. Events must be bound to an element that 
      existed at load time.
$(this) or $(e.target) is button.edit
*/
/*
B: Get the .closest() <tr>
C: In this <tr> find() .each() td.content and toggle the
   [contenteditable] attribute true/false
D: In this <tr> find() td[contenteditable] and .focus() on
   the first one .eq(0). Note: $(this)[0] is a dereferenced
   "this" because jQuery will not recognize the JavaScript
   method .toggleAttribute()
*/
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
  var row = $(e.target).closest('tr'); //B
  row.find('.content').each(function() {
    $(this)[0].toggleAttribute('contenteditable');
  }); //C
  row.find('[contenteditable]').eq(0).focus(); //D
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped contacts">
      <caption style='caption-side:top'><h4>Contacts</h4></caption>
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add">Add Contacts</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm amazed, I feel like I learned so much from this answer. Thank you so much for writing such a detailed response, solution and all the extra knowledge you put in. This helped me a long way in finding the last piece of the puzzle I've been working on the past week. Everything works now! :)

Comment: That's awesome, I'm glad I could help. Happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you give the same id #editBtn to multiple elements. That is incorrect, an id must be unique in the scope of an HTML document.

Secondly i assume that you place the click event of the editBtn only on the page load. But since you generate these elements with AJAX, the click event won't bind on them. You need to call the $('#editBtn').on('click', function()) event, on the success/done of the AJAX  data.

Thirdly, this:

```
var par = $(this).parent().parent();
```

will not work. The editBtn is inside a p, so the $('#editBtn').parent().parent() is the td, not the tr. You need to add one more parent, although trying to retrieve data, traversing the DOM this way is a bad practice and can lead to code breaking and more difficult maintenance. It is better to use specific ids or data attributes.

Comment: Thank you for that knowledge, I'll look into a way to generate unique IDs on the edit buttons. I just started with AJAX a couple of days ago, so I'm not fully aware of everything about the done function. Could you give an example of what you mean with calling the click event on the done? I'm only using done like this right now: getPersons().done(handlePersons). Do you mean I should be doing it like this: getPersons().done(*click event here*)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the data.

Simply **add data to each dynamically generated row** (tr element):

```
function handlePersons(data){ 
    var table = document.getElementById('persons_table');
    data.forEach(function(object) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.setAttribute('data-id', object.ID) // adding data
        tr.setAttribute('data-name', object.Info.Name) // adding data
        tr.setAttribute('data-email', object.Info.Email) // adding data
        tr.setAttribute('data-phone', object.Info.PhoneNumber) // adding data
        tr.innerHTML = 
        '<td>' + object.ID + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.Name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.Email + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + object.Info.PhoneNumber + '</td>' +
        `<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="editBtn" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button></p></td>' +
        '<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></p></td>`;
        table.appendChild(tr);
        });
    }
```

...then **use the edit button's position within the table to locate its parent row and read its data** as needed:

```
$('.btn-xs').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').css('background', 'pink')
    id = $(this).parents('tr').data('id')
    name = $(this).parents('tr').data('name')
    email = $(this).parents('tr').data('email')
    phone = $(this).parents('tr').data('phone')
    alert(id + '\n' + name + '\n' + email + '\n' + phone)
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/ztue5qhd/2/)

Comment: This is so strange, I can't seem to get it to work. I don't know how I can troubleshoot it either. The only thing I can think of that's different is that this line data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" actually does something on my end. Could that be interfering? I understand it could be interfering with alert(), but I feel like console.log(id) should still work. To be clear, it isn't logging anything at all, like I didn't even click the button. I've tried '#editBtn", and I've tried removing the button ID and called '.btn-xs' like in your example. Just... nothing.

Comment: Can you try adding the click handler dynamically as well, right after you create your button. If you are going to use the button’s ID then make sure you have a unique ID for each button you create (you are currently using the same ID for every button), and use the unique ID for each individual click event. I was adding click events after I populated all the data, but you waiting for data returned from an asynchronous ajax call, so you should add your events dynamically with your buttons.